# CGPattern with swift

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, draw

i want to use

```
func CGContextSetFillPattern(_ c: CGContext!,
                       _ pattern: CGPattern!,
                       _ components: UnsafePointer<CGFloat>)
```

in my drawing app , to fill with pattern ...
how can i implement `CGPattern` using swift ??
CGContext Reference [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetFillPattern)

```
 func drawLineFrom(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {

// 1
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
tempImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))

// 2
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y)

// 3
CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound)
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushWidth)
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1.0)
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)

// 4
CGContextStrokePath(context)

// 5
tempImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
tempImageView.alpha = opacity
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211720/trouble-using-callbacks-with-cgpattern-in-swift3 for a Swift 3 version of using CGPattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this links
[Quartz 2D programming Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html) and [CGPattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPattern/index.html). In shortcut to use fillpatern you need to write a callback function that draws one instance of pattern, and later you pass the pointer to callback to cgpatterncreate.

Here you have tutorial how you can make it in obj-c [cgpatternref obj-c](http://blog.robertturrall.com/tag/cgpatternref/) you can easly translate it to swift