# User drawing a line / path with a custom brush tip or a stroke image? [Swift | Objective C | iOS]

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, drawing, paint

User drawing a line and dotted/dashed lines are pretty straight forward. I am able to do that with something like:

```
            context.addPath(path)
            context.setLineCap(.round)
            context.setLineWidth(action.strokeWidth)
            context.setLineDash(phase: 0, lengths: [6, 9])
            context.setStrokeColor(action.color.cgColor)
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a user generated line / curve drawing with a custom brush tip or a pattern. I tried doing something like colorWithPatternImage but that doesn't solve my issue because what it does it just fill the view's background with a textured image pattern and not the line itself. Something like:

Example image of a brush stroke I'd like to accomplish:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend reading [getlooseleaf](https://getlooseleaf.com/opensource/) as there are several solutions. some involve shaders, some would go for `CGPatternDrawPatternCallback` functions where here is a Stack Overflow [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211720/trouble-using-callbacks-with-cgpattern-in-swift3) how to do that in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a project that include free hand draw feature and I saw there is no source or example to learn how to do custom brushes, then after studying a lot of topics on core graphics and spending days for tests I found a solution for creating custom brushes like spray or any pattern that you want.

All these brushes can be draw with [CGLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cglayer). Logic of this operation is instead of doing hard math and calculating pixels just draw your pattern image on this type of layer and pass this guy to your [drawing context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext) and you will see the what you want. Before giving and example code to let you understand better let me share this info with you...

Apple says :

> CGLayer no longer recommended (because of it's not stable)

Thats why think twice before using it on commercial project.

***FYI: This code not tested so please correct it in your side if there is a problem because my aim is only sharing my knowledge on this topic.***

```
private func drawWithCustomBrush(brushSize size: CGSize, brushPattern pattern: UIImage, drawAtPoint atPoint: CGPoint) -> UIImage? {
    
    // Create drawing context and adjust it's settings
    let canvasSize = view.bounds.size
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvasSize) // Preferred options is much more faster than custom options
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    context.interpolationQuality = .high
    context.setAlpha(1.0)
    
    // Optionally you can draw background image
    // YOUR_BG_IMAGE.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
    
    // Create CGLayer with drawing context and draw your pattern with context that CGLayer gives us
    let layer = CGLayer(context, size: size, auxiliaryInfo: nil)
    // Get drawing context from the layer for drawing pattern on this layer
    guard let layerContext = layer?.context else { return nil }
    layerContext.interpolationQuality = .high
    // Draw pattern (as cgImage) on layer with layer context
    layerContext.draw(pattern.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    // Calculate pattern layer position or rect
    let layerRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: atPoint.x - size.width / 2,
                                           y: atPoint.y - size.height / 2),
                           size: size)
    // Now draw the layer our canvas by using drawing context [Not Layer Context!]
    context.draw(layer!, in: layerRect)
    
    // Create result image from current drawing context
    guard let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
    // Clean up the drawing environment
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    // Return your new image
    return finalImage
}
```

**BONUS:-**

For get rid of unwanted copy of pattern for different colors use this UIImage extension function to re-color your pattern.

```
func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    let maskImage = cgImage!
    
    let width = size.width
    let height = size.height
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!
    
    context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
    context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    context.fill(bounds)
    
    if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
        let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        return coloredImage
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

As you can see how it's easy with CGLayer. Now you can create your custom brushes as you like only with passing a single UIImage [it should be png].